What is the probability that Louis and Zoe meet each other at the airport in the rain, but not at the bus station or train station?
Louis plans to pick up his friend Zoe at the national airport this weekend. Zoe, whom Louis has been hoping to meet for a long time, is also planning to fly back to her country and arrive at the same airport this weekend. The probability that it will rain this weekend is 0.2. There are two possible stops near the national airport where they might meet (the bus station or the train station). The probability that Louis will stay at the bus station is 0.2, and the probability that Zoe will stay at the bus station is 0.5. Their travel plans are independent of each other and of the weather. What is the probability that Louis and Zoe meet each other only at the national airport in the rain, without meeting at the bus or train station, in a romantic setup?
My draft idea is that simply considering the probability that Louis and Zoe meet only at the national airport, in the rain, and not at any other location.
$
P(\text{Meet at airport in rain only}) = P(\text{Rain}) \times P(\text{No meeting at bus or train stations})
$
, where $P(\text{No meeting at bus or train stations}) = P(\text{No meeting at bus station}) \times P(\text{No meeting at train station}) 
$
Is there a good way to calculate the correct probability in this situation?

There are 3 possible meeting points, bus station, train station and airport. The probabilities you have given are incomplete.

The problem is phrased ambiguously, but here's one way to interpret it:

Each person travels to the airport either by bus or by train, and chooses their method at random, independent of the weather and the other party's choice.  Louis travels by bus with probability $1/5$ (and by train with probability $4/5$).  Zoe travels by bus with probability $1/2$ (and by train with probability $1/2$).  It rains with probability $1/5$.  What is the probability that it rains and Zoe and Louis choose different travel methods?

In this case, the answer is simply
$$
p=\frac{1}{5}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{10}.
$$
Note that under this interpretation, the method proposed in the question is not correct, because "meeting at bus station" and "meeting at train station" are not independent (indeed, they're mutually exclusive).
Ambiguity arises if either party may travel directly to the airport (by taxi, perhaps?), without stopping at either the bus station or the train station.  I've assumed this is not possible.  If it is possible, then the problem is ill-specified; we have no way to guess the probability of this third possible travel method.

Thanks! I hadn’t fully considered the difference between mutually exclusive and independent events. Thanks for pointing out this was a mutually exclusive, that made a huge difference! More description or assumption... the probability that Louis will stay at the bus station is 0.2, stay at the train station is 0.2, stay at the pick-up area is 0.6 (either by taxi, or drive by himself); the probability that Zoe will stay at the bus station is 0.5, stay at the train station is 0.1, stay at the pick-up area is 0.4.  Would it be complete under this interpretation?

Note that Zoe only has one way to travel is by airplane due to she plan to fly back to her country, same as Louis. After arriving at national airport, Zoe will stay at possible stops, pick-up area, bus station or train station.
